# Bifurcations in Statistical Physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, glass, soft-matter, bifurcation

I am currently a grad level student in physics with much interest in statistical and soft-matter physics (equilibrium and out of equilibrium); I am currently taking a course in numerical methods for bifurcations theory, and the course does not really deal with physical systems. I was wondering if any of you could recommend some texts / articles that applied or discussed bifurcations in soft matter systems or out of equilibrium physics (eg glasses) ?

Comment: Maybe this one:   Steven Strogatz, Non-linear Dynamics and Chaos: With applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry and Engineering, Perseus Books, 2000

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist thank you for your reply ! I was looking for something maybe more advanced as I’ve already gone through Strogatz

Comment: I would suggest the classical book of De Gennes (nobel prix for the theory of polymers and liquid crystals) Introduction to polymer dynamics (https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-polymer-dynamics/2B19CE3FAC2153AB33D516D142096859). This book contains the fundamental for soft matter and chemistry from a dynamical systems point of view.

Comment: Also, the article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921452698011843 is interesting if you are more interested in glass and that kind of subset of soft matter.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply ! I had been thinking of a bifurcation approach to glasses for a while now ... Hopefully this will satisfy my questions